# NSViewController crashes when another viewController is shown as sheet

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I have an NSViewController which contains a button. This button is hooked up to another NSViewController in the storyboard so that when the button is pressed, the secondViewController is shown as a Sheet overlay. This works great and I get the look that I want, but a problem occurs when I subclass NSViewController and assign this subclass to the SECOND NSViewController. The first one works fine whether it has a custom class or not. If i do indeed assign a custom class to the second one, i leave the class exactly how it is created as shown below, but when I press the button, I get no error code (other than the annoying LLBD print in the console) and the app crashes. If someone could advise as to what I am doing incorrectly, or perhaps a way to get a better error log so i can troubleshoot a bit better, that would be appreciated. Please ask for more information / screenshots. Answers in both Swift and objective-c are fine.

```
import Cocoa

class CustomVC: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

The below code is for my initial view controller. It contains 3 sets of data to fill the tableView depending on which segment of a NSSegmentedContoller is pressed. The sheet is going to be used to add a new item to the array - it will pop over the screen so that I can enter new details before saving them into one of the arrays. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

var currentSegment = 0
var tableViewDataSite = ["Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4", "Site 5"]
var tableViewDataSection = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4", "Section 5", "Section 6"]
var tableViewDataArea = ["Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 3", "Area 4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "tableViewCellDidFinishEditingText:", name: NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

//MARK: - TableView Datasource & Delegate

func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView!) -> Int {
    switch currentSegment {
    case 0:
        return tableViewDataSite.count
    case 1:
        return tableViewDataSection.count
    case 2:
        return tableViewDataArea.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject! {

    switch currentSegment {
    case 0:
        return tableViewDataSite[row]
    case 1:
        return tableViewDataSection[row]
    case 2:
        return tableViewDataArea[row]
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableViewCellDidFinishEditingText(notification:NSNotification) {
    let fieldEditor: NSTextView? = notification.userInfo!["NSFieldEditor"] as? NSTextView

    switch currentSegment {
    case 0:
        tableViewDataSite.removeAtIndex(tableView.selectedRow)
        tableViewDataSite.insert(fieldEditor!.textStorage.string, atIndex: tableView.selectedRow)

        //Fetch the Site object from parse and change the name to fieldEditor!.textStorage.string
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    case 1:
        tableViewDataSection.removeAtIndex(tableView.selectedRow)
        tableViewDataSection.insert(fieldEditor!.textStorage.string, atIndex: tableView.selectedRow)

        //Fetch the Site object from parse and change the name to fieldEditor!.textStorage.string
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    case 2:
        tableViewDataArea.removeAtIndex(tableView.selectedRow)
        tableViewDataArea.insert(fieldEditor!.textStorage.string, atIndex: tableView.selectedRow)

        //Fetch the Site object from parse and change the name to fieldEditor!.textStorage.string
        tableView.reloadData()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

//MARK: - IBActions

@IBAction func segemtnedControlDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {
    let segmentedControl = sender as NSSegmentedControl
    currentSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegment
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

[image: image1]
[image: img3]
[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now feel very stupid as I have found the problem, I was running Yosemite Beta 4, and Xcode Beta 7. These don't work very well together apparently. Now that I have updated, it all works well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the button hooked up to another NSViewController? Prior to assigning the second view to the subclass, were there any other properties or methods in the original controller? Where and what action is being targeted by the button?

Can you post the error log?

Comment: I basically control-dragged from the NSButton to the second NSViewController. There were a couple methods in the original view controller which I have appended to my question. I don't mean to be stupid, but as no error is posted in the console, how to I go about getting an error log? Thanks, Jack

Comment: Can you post the storyboard and the connection of that button to the second view controller? I am curious to see what the action is in the second view controller. Am I understanding it correctly that when you assign the subclass of nsviewcontroller to the second view and press the button from the first view controller, that is when it crashes? @JackC

Comment: Thats right, Ive added some images to my answer. @contactritsard